# createElement().download throws error in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a function, where I have to create CSV file from JSON text, though I have copied it from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/).Some of the function is not working and throwing error on my typescript file.I actually down know if I am using it correctly on my typescript file or not.
link.download throws error **property 'link' does not exist on type 'HTMLAnchorElement'**

```
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(CSV);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = uri;
link.style.cssText = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = fileName + ".csv";
```

Not able to understand this error.Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Re edit: http://jsbin.com/wapotab/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem you describe now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set `link.link.download`

`link` doesn't have a `link` property so `link.link` is `undefined`.

`undefined.download` is therefore an error, because undefined values can't have properties.

Comment: @Abhishek — Because it uses `link.download` not `link.link.download`.

Comment: @Quentin- I have updated the question, extra link was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin has pointed out, your next to last line needs to be removed or you end up looking for link.link.download. It should read:

```
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(CSV);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = uri;
link.style.cssText = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = fileName + ".csv";
```

Comment: But still its all what I copied from link http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/,its same over here.

Comment: @Abhishek — It is not the same.

Comment: I have updated the question, extra link was my mistake